# Getting an image from the Intel RealSense Depth Camera

Tags: image, input-devices

Does anybody know how to make the "Module Depth" of an Intel RealSense camera work in Mathematica 12.0?

I can use the "Module RGB" with

```
ImageCapture[
  ImagingDevice -> "Intel(R) RealSense(TM) Depth Camera 435 with RGB Module RGB"])
```

and get an image like for any normal camera, but

```
ImageCapture[
  ImagingDevice -> "Intel(R) RealSense(TM) Depth Camera 435 with RGB Module Depth"]
```

just gives me an empty frame?

Switching the stereo mode on or off via the RealSense Viewer application has no effect.

Comment: Is it still black/empty if you apply `ImageAdjust` to the frame?

Comment: ImageAdjust[
 ImageCapture[
  ImagingDevice -> 
   "Intel(R) RealSense(TM) Depth Camera 435 with RGB Module Depth"]] gives "Expecting an image or graphics instead of [the empty frame]"

Comment: It's not an empty frame or black image then - it's something else.  What is the result of `Head[ImageCapture[ ImagingDevice -> "Intel(R) RealSense(TM) Depth Camera 435 with RGB Module Depth"]]`

Comment: The result is "DynamicModule"

Comment: Use `ImageAdjust@CurrentImage[ImagingDevice -> "Intel(R) RealSense(TM) Depth Camera 435 with RGB Module Depth"]` because `ImageCapture` returns a live preview, not an image which can be adjusted.

Comment: `ImageAdjust@CurrentImage[ImagingDevice->"Intel(R) RealSense(TM) Depth Camera 435 with RGB Module Depth"]`  returns "CurrentImage::checkcam: The camera Intel(R) RealSense(TM) Depth Camera 435 with RGB Module Depth is not available. Check that the camera is properly connected and that it is not currently in use by another application." Strange because "....Moduule RGB" still works so the cam is not used by another app ?!?

Comment: Maybe you should list `$ImagingDevices` here, or do `FindDevices[]`. There might be another device name through which you can access the depth camera.  Unfortunately because I don't have one I cannot test it myself. Also have you closed the _RealSense Viewer_ application? You might want to kill the process because it could be using the camera.

Comment: `$ImagingDevices` -> Out[10]= {Intel(R) RealSense(TM) Depth Camera 435 with RGB Module Depth,Intel(R) RealSense(TM) Depth Camera 435 with RGB Module RGB}   `FindDevices[]` is currently stalling loading from server...

Comment: By the way, I have also the new 515 model. Exact same problem: RGB works while Depth is failing with "...Depth is not available..."

Comment: Even after a refresh reboot, same problem and I do not see any 'realsense' or anything resembling  in the processes list

Comment: You'll probably need help from Wolfram. In the meantime, I can suggest a workaround: if you are prepared to use `ExternalEvaluate` you could return the frame as a `ByteArray` to mathematica through python https://pypi.org/project/pyrealsense2

Comment: I will ask Wolfram - thanks for the pyrealsense2, I will try it. Also trying on my Ubuntu box but it needs more work, compiling the realsense lib, etc. If I get a solution, I will update this case. Regards